# Matlab - read unstructured file

Tags: matlab

I'm quite new with Matlab and I've been searching, unsucessfully, for the following issue: I have an unstructure txt file, with several rows I don't need, but there are a number of rows inside that file that have an structured format. I've been researching how to "load" the file to edit it, but cannot find anything. 
Since i don't know if I was clear, let me show you the content in the file:

8782  PROJCS["UTM-39",GEOGC.......

1 676135.67755473056 2673731.9365976951 -15 0

2 663999.99999999302 2717629.9999999981 -14.00231124135486 3

3 709999.99999999162 2707679.2185399458 -10 2

4 679972.20003752434 2674637.5679516452 0.070000000000000007 1

5 676124.87132483651 2674327.3183533219 -18.94794942571912 0

6 682614.20527054626 2671000.0000000549 -1.6383425512446661 0

...........

8780 682247.4593014461 2676571.1515358146 0.1541080392180566 0

8781 695426.98657108378 2698111.6168302582 -8.5039945992245904 0

8782 674723.80100125563 2675133.5486935056 -19.920312922947179 0

16997 3 21

1 2147 658 590

2 1855 2529 5623

.........

I'd appreciate if someone can just tell me if there is the possibility to open the file to later load only the rows starting with 1 to the one starting with 8782. First row and all the others are not important.
I know than manually copy and paste to a new file would be a solution, but I'd like to know about the possibility to read the file and edit it for other ideas I have.
Thanks!

Comment: When you "load" the file, did you just want to store the text in a character array, or did you want to do some processing as you read each line?

Comment: Thank you @ rayryeng.Before you posted I managed to do, somehow, what I wanted. I used fopen, and combining fget and textscan I managed to read every line. But then I have another problem (I´m very lousy with MATLAB). Let me explain. I wrote:
D=textscan(B,'%s %s  %s %s %s '); 
RowNo= D{1}{1};X1= D{2}{1};Y1= D{3}{1};Z1= D{4}{1};Index1= D{5}{1};
And I was happy because when I checked the value for,i.e,Z1, I got let´s say -10. But if I try Z1=Z1+10 i don't get 0 but some 3dim matrix. I tell you I'm learning by myself, so I may make very mistakes which may seem stupid for experts.

Comment: I understand that I don't have a number but a matrix which assigns some values to -,1 and 0.
To be more clear, what I want now that I can "read" the txt file is, for the first row, give value 1 to RowNo, make X1 iqual to 676135.67755473056, Y1 to....so i can, let's say, change Z1 and save the same line with the change in Z1, then proceed to the following row...
Now I just want to know how to make RowNo, X1, Y1,..."numbers", the rest i can find it out myself...hopefully. 
I'll appreciate your answers. Meanwhile, I'll keep on looking for a solution, maybe I manage myself to find it :)

Comment: STR2NUM!! I told you i´m very lousy with Matlab, but i found the solution...or it looks like. Thanks for all the answers, hope i´m learning more and more now and I don´t need help.

Answer (score 0):

```
% Now lines{i} is the string of the i'th line.
lines = strsplit(fileread('filename'), '\n')

% Now elements{i}{j} is the j'th field of the i'th line.
elements = arrayfun(@(x){strsplit(x{1}, ' ')}, lines)

% Remove the first row:
elements(1) = []

% Take the first several rows:
n_rows = 8782
elements = elements(1:n_rows)
```

Or if the number of rows you need to take is not fixed, you can replace the last two statements above by:

```
firsts = arrayfun(@(x)str2num(x{1}{1}), elements)
n_rows = find((firsts(2:end) - firsts(1:end-1)) ~= 1, 1, 'first')
elements = elements(1:n_rows)
```